# How to backup/restore Firefox bookmarks in JSON format from the command line?

Tags: firefox, firefox-extensions, bookmarks

In Firefox I can open the bookmark management via the menu `Bookmarks` → `Show All Bookmarks` and use the functions `Backup` resp. `Restore` to save resp. load an entire bookmark tree in JSON format.

As far as I understand, this information is stored in the user's profile as a sqlite database (`places.sqlite`). So Firefox has built-in functions to convert between the `sqlite` database and the JSON format.

Is it possible to perform this operation from the command line without starting Firefox? In other words, is there a Firefox command-line option that allows me to do

```
$ exportbookmarks places.sqlite places.json
$ importbookmarks places.json places.sqlite
```

Background to my question is that I would like to do some batch manipulation of Firefox bookmarks without using Firefox's menus.

Also, AFAIK, dumping the `sqlite` database is not a very good option because

1. JSON is easier to parse than an SQL dump, and
2. I would have to reconstruct the bookmark tree from a flat table.

So, does Firefox offer such a function as a command-line option?

Comment: Why aren't you modifying the database directly using SQL?

Comment: @CristianCiupitu: I am trying this as well, but manipulating JSON is much easier IMO.

Comment: You could try to find out how the unit tests from [`toolkit/components/places/tests/unit/test_bookmarks_json.js`](https://dxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/toolkit/components/places/tests/unit/test_bookmarks_json.js) can be run, and modify them for your needs. The meat seems to be `BookmarkJSONUtils.exportToFile` and `BookmarkJSONUtils.importFromFile`.